# Error use php preg_match not match string

Tags: php, regex

I need get string follow this format (C-001 and C-001-C)

```
C-001 (match)
C-002C (not match)
C-003-C (match)
D-004 (not match)
```

This is my code

```
if(preg_match("/^C-[0-9]$/", $input_line, $output_array)) {
    print_r($output_array);
} else {
    echo "NOT MATCH";
}
```

But result show 3 string (C-001, C-002C, C-003-C), C-002C is wrong, how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current regex you are looking for `C-` followed by **1** digit. If you want 3 digits you should use `[0-9]{3}`

```
^C-[0-9]{3}$
```

If you want to also allow another `-C` you can use `(-C)?` (the question mark is there as an optional group:

```
^C-[0-9]{3}(-C)?$
```

Here is a working example:
https://regex101.com/r/0JHN43/1

And this one is inside the `preg_match` block you have:

```
if(preg_match("/^C-[0-9]{3}(-C)?$/", $input_line, $output_array)) {
```